# C#: How to use return from a different class

Tags: c#, return

Since I'm a total beginner I don't know much about C# yet.
I want to use the returned string from Method 1 in my main method.
Shouldn't I be able to use it since `Method1` is public?

```
public string Method1()
{
    Console.Write("Vorname: ");
    string vorname = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.Write("Nachname: ");
    string nachname = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.Write("Adresse: ");
    string adresse = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());

    string info = vorname + nachname + adresse;
    return (info);
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string dateipfad = @"C:\Users\kaihe\Documents\persönliche_informationen.txt";

    AllMethods txtfileabfrage = new AllMethods();
    txtfileabfrage.Method2();

    AllMethods input = new AllMethods();
    Console.WriteLine(info);
    File.WriteAllText(dateipfad, info);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: What is the class name that contains this code?

Comment: Method1 needs to be static if you want to call it from a static method. And the Convert.ToString is unnecessary because Console.ReadLine returns a string already.

Comment: Where are you trying to call Method1()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method1 should also be *static* since you are calling from Main which is static.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the static keyword to Method1() you will be able to call Method1() from the main method.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String returnedValue = Method1();
    }

    public static string Method1()
    {

        Console.Write("Vorname: ");
        string vorname = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Nachname: ");
        string nachname = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Adresse: ");
        string adresse = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());

        string info = vorname + nachname + adresse;
        return (info);

    }
```

Comment: You need to save the returned value to a variable otherwise it cannot be used.

Comment: Well actually there is no need to store the returned value. You could use it like so: Console.WriteLine(Method1());

Comment: If you look at OP's original code - you will see that "info" (presumably the expected returned value) is used twice - so storing in a variable IS required (calling method1 twice would result in requiring the data to be input twice).

Comment: Yes I agree that OP wants to store the output of his method however it is still untrue that "You need to save the returned value to a variable otherwise it cannot be used".